# Make two objects touchable which were created with a function (LUA, Corona)

Tags: function, lua, coronasdk, addeventlistener

I gues this is a real newbie question,

but I have the following code:

```
local function createCircle()
[...]
circle = display.newCircle( positionX, positionY, circleRadius )
[...]
end

function circle:touch( event )
   if event.phase == "ended" then
      scaleCircle(self,scaleUp)
   end
   return true;
end
circle:addEventListener("touch", circle)
```

I cleaned it up a bit, to concentrate on the important things.

My problem right now is: I can touch one circle and scale it. But this works only for one of the circles (I want to create like 3 or 4 of them). And I guess it only works for the last circle which was created.

I guess the main problem here is, that all circles I create with "createCircle()" are named "circle". So the evenListener only works for the "circle" I created.

Any ideas how I can select the other circles I created?

thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solved it:

```
local function createCircle()
  --[[ MORE CODE ]]--
   table.insert(circleTable, display.newCircle( positionX, positionY, circleRadius ) )
   --[[ MORE CODE ]]--
end

function onObjectTouch(event)
   local self = event.target
   if event.phase == "ended" then
        --[[ MORE CODE ]]--
   end
   return true;
end

local function addTouchListeners()
   for _, circle in ipairs(circleTable) do
      circle:addEventListener("touch", onObjectTouch)
   end
end

createCircle()
addTouchListeners()
```

I guess Dream Eaters solution should work as well. But I had another mistake in calling my createCircle() function. I solved this with creating a function for the TouchListeners and call it AFTER the createCircle() function.

Hope this helps other people with similar problems.

Answer (score 1):

You **MUST** use tables. For eg.:

```
circles = {}
local function createCircle()
  --[[ MORE CODE ]]--
  table.insert( circles, display.newCircle( positionX, positionY, circleRadius ) )
  --[[ MORE CODE ]]--
end
function circle:touch( event )
   if event.phase == "ended" then
      scaleCircle(self,scaleUp)
   end
   return true;
end
for _, circle in ipairs( circles ) do
  circle:addEventListener("touch", circle)
end
```

Comment: I read some tutorials about tables.

Your solution seems to be the way to go, but I still have a problem:
the "function circle:touch(event)" gives me an error, because "circle" is not really defined. How can I bypass that? I'm coding on this problem now for several hours :/

Comment: to be correct:
"attempt to index global 'circle' (a nil value)" is the error message I get.