# addEventListener: Only one object hits the endded phase

Tags: api, events, lua, coronasdk

I have a problem with addEventListener "touch". When two or more object are located nearby and activated with one "touch" only one object hits the endded phase.

What I've tried:

```
function theBall(event)
    local ball = event.target.id.id

    if event.phase == "began" then
        print("began")
        display.getCurrentStage():setFocus(event.target)
    end

    if event.phase == "ended" or event.phase == "cancelled" then
        print("ended")
        display.getCurrentStage():setFocus(nil)
    end

end

invisibleBall[ball]:addEventListener( "touch", theBall)
```

in simulator output:

```
began
began
began
ended
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but can it be the same issue as mentioned here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/15096148/1150918
?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a:

```
return true
```

at the end of your function, if not the event propagates to any objects below it.  This is by design.  Just put that return true before the last end and you will be all taken care of.